# Python: default variable in definition not defined when importing module

Tags: python, import, module

Let's say I have a module `foo.py` that contains the following function:

```py
def bar(var=somedict):
    print(var)
```

In my main program, `main.py`, I import this module, define the variable `somedict` and then run the function `bar`:

```py
from foo import *
somedict = 'foobar'
bar()
```

The idea is that `somedict` is passed along as default parameter without having to specify it explictly (which I'd like to avoid for the actual program I'm writing).

However, Python throws a `NameError: name 'somedict' is not defined`. How can I still import the module and have the desired 'passing along of the default variable'? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`somedict` is not defined during import. So `from foo import *` throws the error `NameError: name 'somedict' is not defined`

So modify `foo.py` as follows

```
somedict={}
def bar(var=None):
    if var is None:
        var=somedict
    print(var)
```

Now, you should be able to do what were trying, in a slightly different form

```
import foo
foo.somedict = {'a':1}
foo.bar()
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem! If I may ask, as a follow-up: is this also possible when the `main.py` script uses a star import, i.e. `from foo import *` ? And if so, how would you then change `somedict` inside the `foo` module? That would make the code even simpler for the end user.